# Importação de Arquivo no R - Pegando apenas parte do nome

Tags: r

To com um arquivo local xlsx, só que o nome do arquivo é randômico (muda data e hora no final do nome do arquivo), e queria saber se tem como ler o arquivo apenas pelo inicio do nome.

Segue o nome do arquivo:

```
df = read_excel("report-R041-20181016102502.xlsx")
```

Por exemplo, o começo dele : report-R041 não muda. Sempre será esse nome.
Tem como eu pegar só pelo inicio ao invés de pegar o nome todo do arquivo?

Comment: Veja a minha resposta, por favor. Creio que é bem mais simples que a sua :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil é com o argumento `pattern` das funções `list.files` ou `dir`.

Como os ficheiros se encontram noutro diretório, primeiro mudar para ele.

```
old_dir <- setwd("C:/tmp/")

fich1 <- list.files(pattern = "^report-R041")
fich2 <- dir(pattern = "^report-R041")

identical(fich1, fich2)    # TRUE
```

No padrão acrescentei o circunflexo para dizer ao motor de expressões regulares que deve procurar no início da palavra.

Agora, depois de processar (ou logo a seguir a ler) os ficheiros pode-se voltar para o antigo diretório.

```
setwd(old_dir)    # Repor o estado do sistema
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte comando:

```
setwd("C:/tmp/")
vetor = grep("report-R041", dir(), value = T)
df041 = readxl::read_xlsx(vetor [length(vetor)], skip = 7)
```

:)